# PHPass: custom character set for hashes

Tags: php, security, encryption, hash, phpass

I'm using PHPass to hash passwords and other authorization tasks. In one or two instances, I want to pass a hash as a parameter in a URL:

```
example.com/verify/foobar/$P$Dg2Ytir3E4xSCEkRzB4W5jsPBQ2u6n0
```

Out of the box, PHPass uses `.` and `/` in the construction of hashes, and this causes problems (see the `/` next to `xxx`s:

```
example.com/verify/foobar/$P$Dg2Ytir3E4xSCxxxxxx/xxxxxxBQ2u6n0
example.com/verify/foobar/$P$Dg2Ytir3E4xSCYtir3E4xBQ2u6n0xxxxx/
```

These hashes confuse my app's router, so I'm wondering if there is a way to modify which characters are used to generate the hashes.

I tried hacking the class by removing the `.` and `/` from the `$itoa64` property in several places, but this will throw errors because the hasher is expecting the character string to be the original length. I could add in different characters to match the length, but I'm hesitant to hack the class *too* much without a better understanding of the implications.

Answer (score 1):

Just [`urlencode($hash)`.](https://www.php.net/urlencode)

```
"example.com/verify/foobar/". urlencode($hash);
```

Comment: I tried that but Chrome seems to decode the url before it hits the router. Not sure about other browsers.

Comment: If you modify the url to `"example.com/verify/foobar/?hash=". urlencode($hash);` you may have better luck.